# How to select all columns names that contain a substring in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to select all of the columns that have a column name that contains the substring 'age_'

```
 id   gender   age_now   age_graduated
 aa     F        21         25 
 bb     M        34         24
```

I only want columns 'age_now' and 'age_graduated'

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using some Python to generate your queries:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)
table = client.get_table(
    client.dataset('public_dump', project='fh-bigquery').table('test201602')) 
pattern_cols = [x.name for x in table.schema if x.name.startswith("inferred")]
print ( "SELECT %s\nFROM `%s.%s.%s`" % (
    ','.join(pattern_cols), table.project, table.dataset_id, table.table_id))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Did not realize this was an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you know columns that are not `age_` prefixed you could use [SELECT * EXCEPT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-except):

```
SELECT * EXCEPT id, gender
FROM tab;
```

---

AFAIK there is no syntax like:

```
SELECT * LIKE 'age_%'
FROM tab
```

So the only solution is to read metadata INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table and build dynamic SQL query.

Comment: 'LIKE' and 'CONTAINS' only works after 'where' not after 'select'

Comment: @a.parris Yes, I know that. `"AFAIK there is no syntax like: SELECT * LIKE 'age_%'`